# gitk lost commits

Tags: git, git-gui, gitk

I was using git gui and my wifi was lost during an operation. Now, when I look at my commit history there are several commits missing, and a gap in the history. Everything before the gap is connected with a red line, everything after by a green line.
What has happened here and how do I go about restoring those lost commits?

[Screenshot](http://imgur.com/4SY5eIL)

Comment: Commits are local, why did you mention the WIFI? You need network cinbection to push/pull.

Comment: I was working on a local repo, which is stored on an SMB share. When the wifi dipped out Windows switched to Offline Files. When wifi was restored, Windows asked me if I wanted to keep the network or local copies of a few files (head was one of them IIRC). I chose to keep the local copies since they should have been the latest.

Comment: Use the command line ans type git status. Then paste the output here.

Comment: $ git status
# On branch Main
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Answer (score 0):

The colors of the lines in gitk is for disambiguating lines that cross. They have no other symbolic meaning.